# Is it possible to connect a smartphone/tablet OLED screen directly as a PC monitor?

Tags: touchscreen, controller

**why?**

Why OLED? mainly because of best contrast by having no backlight annoying leakage.

Why smartphone or tablet screen? because of size, resolution and price.

**usage requirements, previous tests, etc**

I was looking for a way to use a tiny smartphone screen near my face, about 30cm is the much I need to focus w/o hurting my eyes out of strain.

My initial obvious research was to buy a Full HD (1080p) OLED monitor (because of possible lower price), but there are only 55"+ TVs available with prices that are at least 3x the full price of my whole desktop computer!!! Probably because of reasons explained here: https://www.monitornerds.com/oled-pc-monitors/, mainly the waste of materials from it's making failures.

I have already used a smartphone like that tho, with lag and lower image quality, thru NoMachine as a server on a linux desktop, the lowered quality only happens because of high framerate required from 3D games or videos tho, not from still images like programming code etc, when NoMachine works marvelously.

Also the small smartphone screen size requires it to be too near my face (less than 30cm), so I still need to find proper lens to use with it (for both eyes). In that case a bigger screen tablet (still OLED tho) could be a MUCH less complex and still cheap alternative.

**So back to the specific problem**

The goal is **performance on high framerates** and keeping the **quality in graphics details**.

Is it possible to, after disconnecting or buying an **OLED tablet/smartphone screen** replacement, **interface it** with a desktop PC thru some kind of **HDMI or VGA controller** to the desktop/notebook PC?

The best would be to provide a model to let a specific answer be provided, but I need to know if it is possible at all with any OLED screen or some specific one, as I would even still need to buy a tablet screen replacement 10"+.

In short, have someone done something like that already? if so, what could you specifically suggest that I could try? what model, pieces, parts I should buy/use?

**interesting but offtopic**

I also wonder if there is something available in the market already capable of doing something like that? Instead of using an arduino or the like.

Btw, if OLED tablets/smartphones had HDMI video **!INPUT!**, this very question would be no more at all...

There are Notebooks with HDMI-IN : http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3532875/tablet-laptop-hdmi-input.html#20229443

There are cards that can capture HDMI and directly convert it to an USB port http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-3562140/input-video-laptop-tablet.html#r20357924 or http://forum.tabletpcreview.com/threads/do-any-tablets-support-av-input.49423/#post-281048 (if this could be plugged on tablet/smartphone as OTG would be great!)

**related:**

[How are OLED screens driven?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23854/how-are-oled-screens-driven)
(sligthly) https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/100427/use-an-android-phone-as-a-monitor-screen-with-av-in-wire
(slightly) https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/134342/can-i-use-my-android-phone-as-a-second-monitor?rq=1

Obs.: I am not an expert at all, just the ideas/coder guy, and will have a friend helping on making the hardware part of it, if not it all. Basically I guess it means I could have questioned more technically if I could.

PS.: 
I dont know if there is a better stackexchange site to ask this kind of question? suggestions are welcome, as such subject is haunting me ;) for some years now...
I am still researching, but I will ask this already.

Comment: *Is it possible to...* I dont' like "is it possible?" questions. Why? Because it **is** possible to do that **if** you have the right knowledge, skills, money etc. You might need access to technical documentation of the display, to write some Verilog code, put it in an FPGA, design and build a PCB etc. If you could do all that then you wouldn't be asking this question. So probably **you** cannot do it as a "hobby project". Sure you can learn to do all the above, do you have **a couple of years?**

Comment: The answer to all these questions are "yes, it is possible".

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie well, **as I said** I am not an expert at all, and I have a busy friend that already spent some years, so I am the team researcher ;)

Comment: @pipe Can this question be migrated to some other stackexchange site? I cant reword it as I am no electronics expert, I am just a coder.. anyway I am downloading the whole page html as bkp info b4 it may get deleted as I saw happening in the past on other stackexchange sites..

Comment: @AquariusPower I seriously doubt this question can fit on any Stack Exchange site. Stack Exchange is designed for narrow and specific questions. You need someone to teach you a lot of stuff and/or design something for you. It would be like asking on Stack Overflow "Is it possible to write a program that makes XYZ? I'm not a coder so I don't know how, please help".

Comment: @pipe "Stack Exchange is designed for narrow and specific questions." this should be everywhere, or a top line at "on-topic", now it is obviously like that but I had to read it to understand, interesting :). I guess I will throw this again in some forum somewhere, may be tomshardware, thx!

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet it to find an OLED panel with a controller that has an eDP (embedded display port) interface. There are plenty on alibaba.com, and you can either bodge yourself a cable [quite hard to get right], or use one of the many available DP (Display port) to eDP adapter boards that exist [much easier as it'll do the pre-emphasis for you]. Most of those adapter boards will also have some electronics to help you drive the power supply for your panel.

The advantages of eDP are that you shouldn't have to figure out the timings yourself and your PC's plug and play should just recognise the panel and configure it. (If you use something with LVDS signalling there's quite a lot of parameters to configure in whatever you use to bridge that to HDMI or Display Port, and it's quite miserable to get them right)

If you're after tablet sized panels be aware that many of them are portrait, and this might cause you issues when gaming as the tear will be vertical and not horizontal.

Comment: thx! the more ready the better, mostly for tests to be sure will work well enough. I expect they let the v-sync work then, screen tearing is another big issue almost as bad as backlight leaking! I will try to buy one of these for tests, I expect they are at least around 1280x800 or more.

Comment: if I am not wrong, there is a lot of misused OLED terminology everywhere on shopping sites, they mix it with "LCD" or "backlight" when naming their products, will be a hard hunt I guess :>

Comment: yes - one of the simplest ways is to look at what things the part is used it and work backwards from there. The HP Spectre x360 15 screen seems a fairly common part but there are plenty of other manufacturers using oled panels(Lenovo, Alienware/Dell,Samsung etc).

Comment: I got an offtopic more expensive tip from http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3532875/tablet-laptop-hdmi-input.html#20229443 about Alienware, may be a refurbished one could do the trick also :)

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to be possible, I believe [this link](https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/2267/whos-doing-galaxy-s4-edp-hack) might have the answer you are looking for.

It is the forum of the Oculus VR community, where users are discussing how to adapt a smartphone OLED screen to display the output of a PC. 
More broadly, I guess that you will find more detailed answers within that community, as they are focused in achieving just what you are.

Comment: very interesting! last talk was 2013, it seems to have moved somewhere? I will see if I can find it later :)

Comment: continue at: https://forums.oculusvr.com/developer/discussion/2844/a-mipi-interface